# Como evitar que me me haga insert al hacer F5

Tags: php, html5

Tengo la siguiente situación. Estoy haciendo un **submit** a un formulario pero cuando refresco la página me vuelve a realizar el **insert** de los datos en la tabla. Buscado en **internet** la solución que se da es que se realice un **redirect** con **header** a la página, lo cual no me es factible.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, existe alguna forma que pueda limpiar las variables sin volver a cargar la página. A continuación les dejo el código con la validación que tengo hecha y ni aun así lo puedo evitar.

```
        if(input_post('enviar')){

            $this->cli->set_comentario();
            $this->u_active = '';
            $this->p_active = 'active';  
            $this->error = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">El comentario ha sido enviado</div>';

        }
```

**Función set_comentario**

```
    public function set_comentario(){

        $id = input_post('id');
        $comentario = input_post('cometario');

        $data = array('idus'=>$_SESSION["credentials"]["userId"],
                      'idtar'=>$id,      
                      'coment'=>$comentario,      
                     );
        classDb::insert_db('comentarios',$data);
    }
```

Gracias

Comment: Yo creo que el problema es que al hacer F5, el usuario vuelve a enviar la información POST (creo que el navegador hasta pregunta por ello) y al hacerlo, logicamente se realiza el insert. Deberías mostrar más código para poder analizarlo mejor, pero así de pronto, podrias realizar primero un SELECT para ver si existe el registro antes de insertarlo o añade un campo timestamp en now() y luego filtra las selects, depende un poco de lo que quieras...

Comment: Si es cierto, creo que entendí mal la pregunta. Podrías despues de guardar, recargar la página con PHP.  Podrías usar esto: header("Refresh:0");

Comment: Acabo de agregar el código de la función **set_comentario**.  Tengo colocado un campo **timestamp** en mi tabla pero si valido por el hasta un segundo me daría distinto y lo volvería a insertar

Comment: Podrías cheuqear con un select si el comentario realizado es exactamente igual al $comentario pasado en $data si no es así que realize el insert de lo contrario lo salta. Un Saludo